# Problem with bluring a light which is behind another object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, masking, blur

Good night, I have a problem on applying blur effect on the node compositer on an object which is between 2 other objects, like this:

[image: That laser shot should be behind the front wing, but in front of the wing behind]
I can't find a way to make the blur look just like the shot itself :S anyone could give me a hand? thanks :D
[image]

Comment: Try and re phrase your question, I don't quite understand what you are looking for. Both images looks like they have blur applied to them. Insufficient blur ? Or is it glow effect you are looking at? Or is it that in the first image, some the laser should be occluded and they are showing through the model? A blend file from you may help us to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: mmmm I need the gaussian blur to be applied to just the shot, the motion blur is applid to both

yeah, I was looking for some glow effect for the shot and adding a blur was the way I figured on how to do that

Comment: You will need to find a way to capture the layer alpha mask for the laser beam you want to affect. Then isolate the laser beam using the mask and apply the blur before compositing on top of the back plate. You might also add the compositing node you have at the moment for a preview of how your node setup is like at the moment.

Comment: can't find a way to diferentiate one object from another, should I separate the wings in 2 different objects on different layers? what if the ship would turn around and shoot? I can't find a way of doing that :S

Comment: Could you attach a simplified version of the blend file and I will try to see if I can create a mask from the laser beam on every animation frame. Basically you will want a black and white mask to tell the compositor which part of the laser you wanna see minus the ship object's alpha.

Comment: I finally solved it by using pass index on the material :) thank you anyway dude :D

Comment: It would help others in future if you post your finding in the answer box below ? Cheer glad you found your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I could fix the problem by using index pass as factor for mixing the image in the compositiing nodes. I used the original image itself and its blurred version as the inputs for the mixing.